# Using QValidator in QCoreApplication

Tags: qt, validating

I want to use QValidator and its subclasses (QRegExpValidator, QIntValidator) in QCoreApplication, but get the following error: "QValidator: No such file or directory"
If I add in .pro file the following line: "QT += gui" - all works fine, but that is not a solution for me.

Is there any technique to use QValidator in QCoreApplications?

Comment: write why you need validators in qt core application. QValidator is design to work with QLineEdit.

Comment: I decided to use QValidator to validate program arguments. Smth like this: if (validator.validate(QString(argv[1]),0) != QValidator::Acceptable ... For examaple, if first parameter is an IP address and I want to check it correctness

Comment: so QValidator is to big machine for you (you don't need intermediate state or cursor information). `QRegExp`, `QString::toInt`, `QString::toDouble` should do the job (if you need localized validation then respective functions of `QLocale` should be ok).

Comment: Thank you! Henceforth I will read qt docs much closer ;) QRegExp & QString done all the job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. QValidator is part of the gui lib. I suppose the Qt devs thought that QValidator makes only sense with Qt's text input classes. I checked again, above statement is still true. However, I looked into the code, QValidator does not depend on any gui stuff. On first glance it seems to be rather stand-alone. So you **might** be able to copy qvalidator.cpp and qvalidator.h from the Qt sources into your sources, do a reasonable amount of adjusting, and integrate this into your code. It might be possible, I don't say it will be easy.

Comment: I thought there is a simple hack to do that. Anyway thank you!